# show and hide divs with jquery using data-link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a country map on the left with different links displaying different areas on it. On the right I have a container that contains the information-divs i want to show depending on which link on the map you have clicked.

I have set the same data-type on the link and the relevant container to show when link is clicked.

How do i go about using jquery to fade out the visible content and then fade in the the relevant content targeting the data-type?

```
<div class="map">
    <a data-link="HQ" title="HQ Gauteng" class="pin pin-1" href=""><img src="images/pin.png" alt=""></a>
    <a data-link="Johannesburg" title="Johannesburg" class="pin pin-2" href=""><img src="images/pin.png" alt=""></a>
    <a data-link="Centurion" title="Centurion" class="pin pin-3" href=""><img src="images/pin.png" alt=""></a>
    <a data-link="NorthWest" title="North West" class="pin pin-4" href=""><img src="images/pin.png" alt=""></a>
    <a data-link="Mapumalanga" title="Mapumalanga" class="pin pin-5" href=""><img src="images/pin.png" alt=""></a>
    <a data-link="Natal" title="Kwazulu Natal" class="pin pin-6" href=""><img src="images/pin.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="maps-wrapper">
    <div data-link="HQ" id="map-1">This is the map container 1</div>
    <div data-link="Johannesburg" id="map-2">This is the map container 2</div>
    <div data-link="Centurion" id="map-3">This is the map container 3</div>
    <div data-link="NorthWest" id="map-4">This is the map container 4</div>
    <div data-link="Mapumalanga" id="map-5">This is the map container 5</div>
    <div data-link="Natal" id="map-6">This is the map container 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean data-link?

Comment: Don't forget to click the checkmark to the left of the most helpful answer!

Answer (score 3):

In Addition with @m59 code,  Try this,

To Show the currently clicked `a` and hide remains

```
$('a').click(function(event) {     
  var current = $(this).attr('data-link');
  $('.maps-wrapper div').hide();
  $('div[data-link='+current+']').show();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[data-link]').click(function() {

  //get this link's dataLink value
  var dataLink = $(this).attr('data-link');

  //select the div with the same value
  var toKeep = 'div[data-link="'+dataLink+'"]';

  //select data-link divs that are not the above div
  $('div[data-link]').not(toKeep).hide();

  //show selected div
  $(toKeep).show();

  //prevent location change
  return false;
});
```

Since you have `href=""` you will also need to `return false` at the end of the click function to prevent a location change. I recommend removing the `href` attribute. It's an optional property.

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/OdItije/4/edit)**

Comment: this only hides the current visible div

Comment: @GavinWood I originally thought you want to hide the element with the same data-link. I must be tired =D Anyway, my updated answer hides others and shows only the element with the same data-link. See the updated demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('maps-wrapper').hide();

  /** trigger function **/
  $('a.pin').click(function(){
    var datalink = $(this).data('link');
    $('.maps-wrapper div').fadeOut('fast');
    $('div[data-link='+datalink+']').fadeIn(1000);
  });

  $('a.pin-1').click();    
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/selvarajblr93/GMUSx/8/